# make: *** makefile. stop

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am new to cmake, and when I compile the makefile using "make -j10" after cmake, it failed and turned out "make: *** makefile. stop." I am really confused. Thanks in advance for precious suggestions!

```
G:\code\c++\assignment2\code\test>mkdir build

G:\code\c++\assignment2\code\test>cd build

G:\code\c++\assignment2\code\test\build>cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29912.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29912.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: G:/vs/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: G:/vs/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found Boost: G:/boost_1_75_0/ (found version "1.75.0") found components: timer chrono
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: G:/code/c++/assignment2/code/test/build

G:\code\c++\assignment2\code\test\build>make -j10
make: ***  makefile. stop.
```

Comment: The message `Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019` means that CMake configures your project for Visual Studio, not for Make.

Answer (score 1):

Run `cmake --build . -j 10` under your *build* directory.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't build makefiles, you built Visual Studio project files, as can be seen from this line:

```
Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
```

To instruct CMake to generate makefiles instead, use cmake's -G flag:

```
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

Or if you didn't intend to build makefiles, you can compile using the generated build system (in this case Visual Studio) as shown in aleck099's answer.